# what does buffer mapped means for PBO?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I need to test the INVALID_OPERATION error for glReadPixels when the PBO is mapped. But not getting what does buffer mapped means exactly.
Following the code part:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, iBufferObj);

    // Bind the buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, *iBufferObj);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, iSize, 0, GL_STREAM_READ); // iSize is my framebuffer size
     glReadPixels(0, 0, iSurfaceWidth, iSurfaceHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    ptr = (GLuint*)glMapBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, iSize, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
     glReadPixels(0, 0, iSurfaceWidth, iSurfaceHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, cBuff); // cBuff client buffer container
     glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
```

Is it correct to expect error on second glReadPixel call, as the buffer is mapped with glMapBufferRange()?

Could you help understanding the concept of mapped buffer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question. [Mapping a buffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping) means that you can access it's contents "directly" via a pointer. This is as opposed to `glBufferSubData` or `glGetBufferSubData`.

And, unless you're using a [really advanced version of OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Persistent_mapping), you cannot use a buffer in any way while it is mapped. This includes reading into it via a PBO read.

Comment: So, when we use glMapBufferRange(), that means buffer is mapped.      "you cannot use a buffer in any way while it is mapped" , does that mean calling glReadPixels after glMapBufferRange() should generate some error (GL_INVALID_OPERATION), as per opengles 3 specification "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to the GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER target and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped."